# Convert multiple line to single list in python

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a file as follows:
using python i want to convert these multiple line to single list as below output. Please help me on this

```
x = {
      "name": "Ken",
      "age": 45,
      "married": True,
      "children": ("Alice", "Bob"),
      "pets": [ 'Dog' ],
      "cars": [
      {"model": "Audi A1", "mpg": 15.1},
     {"model": "Zeep Compass", "mpg": 18.1}
  ],
}

 pdf = FPDF()
 pdf.add_page()
 pdf.set_font("Arial", size=12)
 x.keys()
 for key in x.keys():
     print(key)
 keys = key.strip().split("\n")
 keys = list(key)
 print(keys)
```

For this I'm getting output as below

```
 ['name']
 ['age']
 ['married']
 ['children']
 ['pets']
 ['cars']
```

expected output:

```
['name','age','married','children','pets','cars']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from fpdf import FPDF
x = {
      "name": "Ken",
      "age": 45,
      "married": True,
      "children": ("Alice", "Bob"),
      "pets": [ 'Dog' ],
      "cars": [
      {"model": "Audi A1", "mpg": 15.1},
     {"model": "Zeep Compass", "mpg": 18.1}
  ],
}

pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_font("Arial", size=12)
list_of_keys = [i for i in x.keys()]
print(list_of_keys)
```

result:

```
['name', ' age', 'married', 'children', 'pets', 'cars']
```

Comment: ['name']
['age']
['married']
['children']
['pets']
['cars']
Iam getting output like this. What should i do?

Comment: I edited my code, is it ok now? can  you please help me on this.